# Insert Reference Page in the middle section instead of in the end

Tags: cross-referencing

I understand the common practice is to insert the Reference page at the end of a report. However, our team decided to insert the Reference page in front of the Appendix section in our report. My question is, if I were to use what I have used in the past, `\bibliographystyle{plain} \bibliography{final_report_ref}`, the reference page would only appear at the end, right? Is there anyway to make it appear in the middle section (i.e. Section 3 Conclusion; Section 4 References; Section 5 Appendix.)? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Because you gave us no MWE we have to guess ...

Something like this:

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@Book{Goossens,
  author    = {Goossens, Michel and Mittelbach, Frank and 
               Samarin, Alexander},
  title     = {The LaTeX Companion},
  edition   = {1},
  publisher = {Addison-Wesley},
  location  = {Reading, Mass.},
  year      = {1994},
}
@Book{adams,
  title     = {The Restaurant at the End of the Universe},
  author    = {Douglas Adams},
  series    = {The Hitchhiker's Guide to the Galaxy},
  publisher = {Pan Macmillan},
  year      = {1980},
}
@article{Heattransfer,
  author  = {Incropera, Frank P. and DeWitt, David P.},
  edition = {Fourth},
  number  = {30},
  pages   = {530},
  title   = {{Introduction to Heat Transfer}},
  url     = {https://www.amazon.com/Introduction-Heat-Transfer-Frank-Incropera/dp/0471457272},
  volume  = {0},
  year    = {2001},
  journal = {missing},
} 
\end{filecontents*}


\documentclass[toc=bibliographynumbered]{scrartcl}

\usepackage{hyperref} % <======================================= for url


\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\section{Section 1}
\section{Section 2}
\section{Section 3}

\nocite{*}
\bibliographystyle{plainurl}
\bibliography{\jobname} % <===================================== no .bib

\appendix

\section{Appendix A}

\end{document}
```

with the resulting pdf:

[image: resulting pdf]

Answer (score 0):

Use `\clearpage` after your `\bibliography{final_report_ref}`command and put what ever you like afterward.

I usually put `\appendix` there and reset/hack `\setcounter{page}{1} \setcounter{chapter}{0}` so that appendixes have their own page numbering.

```
\bibliography{final_report_ref}
\clearpage
% put your stuff after this.
```